Concat an Alias in Snowflake
I am working on a query in Snowflake and am wanting to create an alias for a column. I know you can do this in other languages but am not sure if snowflake supports this.
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN s.agi BETWEEN (EXTRACT('year', current_timestamp()) || '-06-01') AND (EXTRACT('year', current_timestamp()) || '-08-31')
THEN s.stageqty END) AS 'FA' || (EXTRACT('year', current_timestamp() || 'Total Shipped Qty'
from Test_Data as s

The error I get is "Syntax error: unexpected ''FA''."
Let me know if there is a way to do this. Thanks in advance!

So you want your column name to be "FA2024Total Shipped Qty"?

I think you'd need to do this via a script that dynamically generates your query, rather than directly in SQL.  I "believe" an alias must be a string at compile time.

Yes I want it named "FA2024Total Shipped Qty"

PIVOT may provide a solution. See this answer

Instead of CASE, get your data in rows, and then pivot with any:
with data as (
    select  sum(o_totalprice) total, 'YEAR_' || extract(year from o_orderdate) year,
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders
    group by all
)

select *
from data pivot(sum(total) for year in (any order by year))
;

Takes this:

To this:

